# how to plot a binomial glmer with two binomial predictors?

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-visualization

I have a response variable called Perceived Personality (responsible-sympathetic) predicted by Birth Order (Firstborn-Laterborn) interacting with Sex (Male-Female), with 2 random effects. I just want to know what kind of graphic I could use to plot this GLMM and the statistical program I could use (using R at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ggplot(exdata, aes(x=BirthO, y=PP, color=Sex,
                      group=Sex)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom="line", size=1)+
  stat_smooth(method="glm", se=FALSE, method.args = list(family=binomial), color='black')
```

If you want your fit to include the random effect:

```
model=glmer(PP~ Sex*BirthO+ (1|ID),data, 
            family=binomial(link = "logit"), 
            control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun=2e5)))
summary(model)
data$fit=predict(model, type = "response")

ggplot(data,aes(BirthO, PP,  color=Sex,
                     group=Sex)) + 
  stat_summary(geom="line", size=0.8) +
  stat_summary(aes(y=(fit)),geom="line", size=0.8, color="black") +
  theme_bw()
```